# Turn off Hibernate hbm.xml XML validation against remote DTD

Tags: spring, hibernate, xml-validation

We're currently using `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean` to configure Hibernate in our app.  It loads about fifty .hbm.xml mapping files, and of late, it appears that loading the DTD, `http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd`, is taking a much-longer-than-usual amount of time.  Everything eventually works, but when one's server takes over a minute to start up, it makes one grumpy.  Here's our doctype, in case we're doing that incorrectly:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

Is there a way to turn validation on and off in, say, in the Spring-managed configuration of LocalSessionFactoryBean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this [thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=943281). It is a bit old, but the last entry said that you have to specifiy exactly that doctype name that is shipped with the hibernate jars.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  So we have to switch back to the sourceforge hosted DTD?

Comment: You have to switch to the DTD that is in the jar file.

Comment: I did a jar -tf hibernate3.jar and the dtd file there is `org/hibernate/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd`.  Doesn't what I've got match that?  Where do I find the actual URL for it?  (Sorry for being so dense.)

Comment: Ahhh, the DTD file itself has a DOCTYPE.  And it still points to the sourceforge hosted file.  I'm pretty sure I changed away from that early on because Hibernate itself complained about it.

Comment: Yep, definitely speeds things up.  Thanks again.

Comment: And yep, that warning cropped up again:  `18:40:30,877  WARN DTDEntityResolver:73 - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!`

I'll keep the warning and the faster startup times.